# Help Understanding auth.log Entry

Tags: authentication, log

Recent Ubuntu (v 18.04) convert and trying to understand a auth.log entry.

```
May  3 00:38:58 dug pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
May  3 00:38:58 dug pkexec[12217]: dug: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/dug] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
```

I don't usually leave my machine on overnight,but 2 nights ago I left it on and came back in the am to find all my applications closed. I was digging through the logs to see what happened and found the above entry as the only thing I didn't understand.

Could somebody explain it please?

Comment: This command appears to run on my system as well, daily in the early morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That appears to be harmless; on my server that happens when it checks for updates

```
Apr 28 05:33:59 SlowerThanInfinity pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Apr 28 05:33:59 SlowerThanInfinity pkexec[24809]: [redacted]: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/[redacted]] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
```

If you look at what the script does, it is associated with
 `unattended-upgrades`

```
#!/bin/sh
# check if package system is locked
# return 0 if unlocked, 2 if locked, 1 on error
set -e

for f in /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock \
    /var/lib/apt/lists/lock /run/unattended-upgrades.lock; do
    [ -e $f ] || continue

    # fuser succeeds if there is at least one user
    if fuser $f; then
        exit 2
    fi
done

exit 0
```

So I doubt this closed your applications unless that happened as a result of something that got installed by `unattended-upgrades`, you could check `/var/log/apt` to see if anything did.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!